# How to create random, unstructured mesh of surface

Tags: mesh-generation, unstructured-mesh, boundary-element-method

I am working on a supersonic boundary element method (https://github.com/usuaero/MachLine). In order to test its sensitivity to the boundary discretization, I'd like to be able to create "random" meshes of simple shapes (e.g. a cone) like what's shown here for a sphere, except using triangles.

[image]

Generating a set of random vertices shouldn't be difficult. What algorithm/tool could I use for then piecing those vertices together into a set of panels?

Comment: Random points on the surface + Delaunay triangulation; but after that, if you don't want triangular elements, you'd have to combine adjacent triangles into other polygons.

Comment: What about using [gmsh](https://gmsh.info/) or [gid](https://www.gidsimulation.com/)?
gmsh is free, and gid is charged.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The fluid-dynamics part of geophysics has a lot of simulations which are on planet-scale and consequently they have existing literature about which meshes of sphere surfaces are well suited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out scipy has an algorithm for generating convex hulls for a set of points, described here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html. I'm not sure what the underlying algorithm is, but it did what I needed it to. Here's my solution coded up:

```py
def _get_random_points_on_surface_of_sphere(N, r):
    """Generates a set of points randomly distributed across the surface of a sphere.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    N : integer
        Number of points.
        
    r : float
        Radius of sphere.
        
    Returns
    -------
    ndarray
        Array of points.
    """

    # Initialize
    points = np.zeros((N,3))

    # Get azimuth angles
    psi = np.random.random(N)*2.0*np.pi

    # Get elevation angles (weighted towards equator, so the distribution remains even)
    theta = np.arccos(1.0-2.0*np.random.random(N))

    # Get coordinates
    points[:,0] = r*np.sin(theta)*np.cos(psi)
    points[:,1] = r*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(psi)
    points[:,2] = r*np.cos(theta)

    return points


def generate_random_sphere(filename, N, r):
    """Generates a random unstructured mesh of a sphere.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    filename : str
        Name of the file to write the mesh to. Must have '.vtk' extension.
    N : integer
        Number of vertices.
        
    r : float
        Radius of sphere.
        Array of points.
    """
    
    # Get vertices
    verts = _get_random_points_on_surface_of_sphere(N, r)

    # Create convex hull
    hull = ConvexHull(verts)

    # Make sure normal vector points inward
    fixed_simplices = []
    for simplex in hull.simplices:

        # Calculate normal and centroid
        centroid = np.sum(verts[simplex,:], axis=0) / 3.0
        normal = np.cross(verts[simplex[1],:] - verts[simplex[0],:], verts[simplex[2],:] - verts[simplex[1],:])

        # Check the normal points outward
        if np.dot(centroid, normal) > 0.0:
            fixed_simplices.append(simplex)
        else:
            fixed_simplices.append(simplex[::-1])

    # Export mesh
    _export_vtk(filename, verts, np.array(fixed_simplices))
```

Here's what one looks like with 500 vertices.

[image: Sphere with random triangular paneling.]

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to compute the ['restricted' Delaunay triangulation](https://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/%7Edey.8/book/Delmesh/chapter13.pdf) of the set of scattered points you place on the surface of the sphere/cone/object you're working with. This will determine the subset of triangular faces of the 3-dimensional Delaunay tessellation (tetrahedrons) induced by the points. The [CGAL library](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal), INRIA's [geogram](https://github.com/alicevision/geogram), or my [jigsaw package](https://github.com/dengwirda/jigsaw) are all options for computing rDTs.

Another option could be to use a surface meshing library to generate a high quality mesh for your surfaces, and then perturb the vertices to degrade its quality. I've had some success using this approach to test the robustness of order-of-accuracy estimates to mesh distortion.